# groupby and pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a file (score.csv) like this:

[image: score.csv]

I need to solve the problem in python using pandas and groupby

The problem is like I have one csv file in which I have a data which I need to group on the basis of some point
the points are

1. I want to group data basis on series id
2. Then find the highest score and percentage
3. To find the userids with closest to 50% data (middle cohort) - in comparison to point 2 for the first testid
4. Then find score of these users for rest of the testids
5. Then normalise the score with the toppers score

The idea is to find the performance of students in each test.
Structure:
Test Series (series_id)-> having multiple tests(test_id)->mapped with users(user_id)-> scores
For each series_id, to find the first test(which is the lowest test_id for each series id), and users with scores between 40-60 in the first test only.

(Now analysis will be done on users found in point 1 for other tests. Meaning I have found users who are scoring around 50 marks and now I will track their journey in other tests.)
Pick the users_ids from above and find scores for other tests as well. Along with this will have to find the highest score in each test to find the ratio of marks_obtained/highest marks in that test. Basically, we want to normalise the scores with respect to the highest scorer to understand the journey of these users.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the groupby function with other aggregating methods:

```
df.groupby('series_id').max('marks_gained')
df.groupby('series_id').mean('marks_gained')
```

You can then find the median and define your 50% cohort by equal distance to that.

```
df.groupby('series_id').median('marks_gained')
```

It's usually better to provide data in a format that is easily reproducible and to be completely explicit about each of your requests(for example one has to guess what you mean by percentage - the percentiles of marks?)